# How to run multiple Putty commands from Notepad

Tags: python, linux, unix, ssh, putty

I have created Python TkInter to open a Putty session as below

```
# If the server name is not empty, open an SSH connection using PuTTY
if server_name:
    #set the putty path
    putty_path = 'C:\\Program Files\\PuTTY\\putty.exe'

    check_db_type = db_type.get().lower()
    check_db_type_action = get_action().lower()
   
    abs_path = resource_path(f"sudo\\{check_db_type}\\{check_db_type}_sudo.txt")
    
    # THIS IS WHAT STARTS THE SSH PUTTY SESSION
    server_command = f'{putty_path} -ssh {username}@{server_name} -pw {password} -m "{abs_path}" -t'
    
    subprocess.Popen(server_command)

    # close the subprocess if it is already running and open a new subprocess
    # with contextlib.suppress(Exception):
    #     subprocess.Popen.terminate()
    # subprocess.Popen(server_command)

else: 
    window.destroy()
```

I am passing the notepad filepath in the server_command. The file contains these commands.

`sudo su - postgres` works well but other commands are not working

```
sudo su - postgres || df -kh
```

I have tried 3 variants of command separation as below but nothing works

```
sudo su - postgres; df -kh

sudo su - postgres && df -kh

sudo su - postgres
df -kh
```

Is there any other way to run multiple commands like these apart from using a text file? Thank you so much

I have tried to separate the 2 commands in the notepad in 3 different ways but only the first command `<sudo su - postgres>` is working. The next command `<df -kh>`, shows filesystem space, is not working as expected

I am using Windows on my laptop but access database servers through Putty remotely

**++Update**

When my team login as ADM (ADM account for users) and then sudo su - username, it opens a different subshell than the previous one. Can check by echo $$.

To put it simply, ADM is parent shell and sudo su - username will open child shell. After sudo su - postgres, all my following commands <uptime; df -kh, etc> running in parent shell in the background. Until I exit sudo su - postgres <CTRL + D> I cannot see the output.

Comment: When you say the commands aren't working, what do you mean? That is, what is happening and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Also, do you need to spawn a separate process to do the SSH work? I mean, do you need to use PuTTY as opposed to a Python library like Fabric (https://www.fabfile.org/)?

Comment: @ndc85430 The second command <df -kh> which is supposed to display the filesystem space available is not showing any output. Not throwing any error, just a blinking cursor after running the first sudo command successfully

Comment: @ndc85430 my teammates mainly use PuTTY. So I thought of automating the login process for multiple servers. I will look into Fabric, thanks.

Comment: The problem here is that the execution stops at `sudo su - postgres` ... the command `df -kh` will be run after you press `Ctrl-D`.  What you **really** want to use is `sudo -u postgres bash -c 'df -kh'` ...

Comment: @tink do I have to do the same if I have 3 or 4 commands instead of just 2? Thanks in advance ya

Comment: Just tack them into the command in the single quotes.  `sudo -u postgres bash -c 'df -kh; command2; command3; command4'` ...